# Grid layout column extends too far

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to use grid layout to create two columns. The right column has a fixed width but the left one should take whatever's left out. However, the problem is that when the content is too long, it extends the left column and causes a horizontal scrollbar in the container.

[image: screenshot of error]

Now I can achieve this with other methods like `calc` but I'm trying to learn grid layout.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/pta2c7um/

Ideally I would want the long title to get truncated respecting the grid structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution:

```
#ticket-viewer .list li{
    /* grid-template-columns: auto 80px; */
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) 80px;
    padding: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

## Working example:

```css
.list{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.list li {
  padding: 0.8rem 0;
  position: relative;
}
.list li small {
  color: #777777;
}
.list li .content {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.list li .right-assist {
  text-align: right;
}
.list.left-assist li, .list.right-assist li {
  display: grid;
}
.list.right-assist li {
  grid-template-columns: auto 40px;
}
.list.dividers li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background: #CCC;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#ticket-viewer{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: flex;
}
#ticket-viewer .list{
    width: 40%;
  height: 560px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#ticket-viewer .list li{
    /* grid-template-columns: auto 80px; */
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) 80px;
    padding: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.truncate {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="ticket-viewer">
  <ul class="list right-assist dividers">
    <li data-id="1" class="">
      <div class="content"><span class="truncate">Test</span><small>Bug/Error on Website</small></div>
      <div class="right-assist">Resolved</div>
    </li>
    <li data-id="2" class="active">
      <div class="content"><span class="truncate">This is a very very long subject</span><small>Feature Request</small></div>
      <div class="right-assist">Resolved</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## Explanation:

`grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) 80px;` step-by-step explanation:

1. Define two columns.
2. The last has fixed 80px width;
3. The first occupies remaining space.

minmax(0, ..) is used to tell browser to shrink width of column, if its content is wider than 1fr (i.e. 1 fraction of remaining space).

[More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)